# Microsoft identity - revoke authorization

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm developing a .NET application that can send emails on behalf of the user using the Graph API.

Users are prompted to authorize the application; The acquired access token is then used to call the Graph API. The refresh token is used to issue a new access token when the old one expires, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Couple of questions / observations:

1. Assume user John authorizes the app to send emails on his behalf. If an administrator removes the app from the azure portal, the access/refresh tokens issued when John authorized the app will still work.

- if the access token is still active, it can be used to call the graph api;
- if the access token is expired, the refresh token can still be used to request a new access token

Is this behavior intended?

After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/users-revoke-access and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0 it seems that simply removing the app from the user doesn't revoke the tokens.

2. Assume user John authorizes the app to send emails on his behalf. If John goes to https://myapplications.microsoft.com and removes the app he won't be able to use the refresh token to get a new access token, which is expected.

However, I've noticed that if John reauthorizes the application to perform actions on his behalf, the application won't show up on https://myapplications.microsoft.com anymore. This behavior seems a bit inconsistent. What's the proper way for a user to revoke access to an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has granted access to the application, Azure AD will issue an **access token** and a **refresh token** for the resource.

The lifetime of the access token is usually about 1 hour. During its lifetime, even if the application is deleted, it is still available, but you will not be able to use the refresh token to obtain the access token again.

If you need to revoke authorization during the lifetime of the access token, please see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: I've noticed that the refresh token will still work if the application is removed from the user by an administrator. Is this intended?
If the user removes the application (by going to https://myapplications.microsoft.com), then the refresh token stops working

Comment: see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Comment: @Timo89   I did a lot of tests on this and came to a conclusion: After you assign the application to a user and use the user to log in to obtain the access token and refresh token, if you use the administrator to remove the user assigned to the application at this time, the refresh token obtained before is indeed available Yes, it can still get a new access token. But if you use the user or the administrator to delete the application, then the refresh token will not be available,because the `client id` must be used when using the refresh token to obtain the access token.