# Check if users deleted in clients Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am integrating Login with Azure AD for one of my clients on my website. I am only targeting one specific group in their organisation, and not everybody in the entire organisation.

This new feature has 2 requirements:

1. We need to create an account for people logging in via their email using our clients Azure AD.
2. We need to run a CRON job daily to check if anybody has been removed in their AD (due to them leaving the company), so we also need to remove their profile in our application.

For number 1, I think it's sufficient to call the /authorization, /token and /userinfo endpoints. Is this correct?

But for number 2, I am having issues to see how this is possible.

When browsing the graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I can find the following 2 API methods:

- GET all users in the organization  /users ---> But i am unsure whether this returns all the users in their AD, or only the ones applicable for my application?
- GET direct members of a group with count  /groups/<id</members  ---> Is this the one I am looking for when they are assigned into a specific group?

I've also found this SO link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553305 which talks about saving the access token and refresh token. Is it possible if I save these two to fetch the userinfo at any point in time? This way I could possibly query all the created accounts each day and if one of them returns a status deleted, or empty I know the account no longer exists? Or is this not an option?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I noticed that my client granted me the User.Read and User.Read.All graph permissions.
But i'm not certain how to call this API? When calling this API in Postman :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/123-this-is-the-id
```

I am getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token is empty.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-07T12:59:05",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Azure AD application has permissions to get user profile from your client's Azure AD?

Comment: According to our client the permissions are set correctly yes!

Comment: If that's the case, then can't you try to read user's profile based on the id stored in your database? If the user is deleted, then you will get a 404 error back. You can then update your database accordingly.

Comment: I am unsure how to read the user's account info with only their ID, don't I need consent of the user first in order to call the userinfo endpoint ?

Comment: You're correct. Considering you're planning on running a background process, your application would ask for "Application" permission (instead of "Delegated" permission) and an admin from your client's Azure AD will need to consent to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Do you know which API method I should then call to be able to retrieve this information? Am I looking into the /users/ graph API method or is there another one more suitable?

Comment: I noticed that my client has granted me the User.Read permission, but I am unable to query this. I have edited my question to include this extra information!

Comment: That’s correct. The API you would want to call is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Comment: I'm getting the "Access token is empty" error when trying to call this API method with my user ID.

Comment: Regarding the error, please see the documentation on using the Graph API. You’ll need to include authorization header in your request.

Comment: This is where my head cannot wrap around it. When using the Authorization header, only "Bearer" seems to be supported, which requires a token. Is this token not only available when the user gives me it's consent? I'm not sure where i can get this token from to read the /users/ endpoint for all my user id's

Comment: Try using Microsoft Graph Explorer instead of Postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237921/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-dennis).